# Can an Israeli who is in the U.S. on 8th Day Pesach eat a Gentile's chametz kosher food?

Tags: halacha, gentiles, passover, chutz-laaretz, chametz-leaven

Someone has both an Israeli family and a Gentile maid living with a U.S. family in the same house on the 8th Day of Pesach.

During the week, the Gentile has been eating her kosher chametz food in the basement kitchen away from the rest of the rest of the household. The Israelis do not have an 8th day of Pesach, however, because Shabbat immediately follows the end of Pesach, they normally would not be eating chametz in the U.S. family's home.

However, assume that the Gentile has some leftover cold chametz kosher food that belongs to her, and she offers to share her food. Is there any problem with the Israelis eating that food on that Shabbat? Can they eat it at the same table as the rest of the family, assuming that they are careful not to get chametz crumbs all over, or do they have to eat only in the chametz kitchen with the Gentile?

Comment: I doubt it would be permissible to eat it at the same place, but +1 for an interesting question.

Comment: "because Shabbat immediately follows the end of Pesach" Are you asking specifically about that kind of year? Why? And why then must you bring in the whole Chutz Laaretz issue?

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/51098/759 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14263/ http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/37033/

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there's an incorrect premise in my own question. Per the answers indicated in [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/37033/israeli-making-pizza-on-last-day-of-pesach-in-the-diaspora) , there are several opinions stating that an Israeli is not allowed to eat Chametz on the 8th day of Pesach when he is in the U.S.

I suspect that this may be a minority opinion or there are others that do allow this. I have had a few religious Israelis staying in my home who travelled, bought and ate Chametz (outside my home) while they were in the U.S. on the 8th day. I assume that they know what they are doing is OK. If they are absolutely wrong, then, maybe I should mark my own question as a duplicate?

Comment: AFAICT it is the majority opinion, in fact. Many Israelis (even religious ones) think Second day YT is 'silly' so don't ask and don't care (IME; I'm not commenting on your particular guests.)